# Why adding constraints removes the ability to resize NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nslayoutconstraint, nswindow, autolayout

[image]

All what I am trying is, to add an NSImageView and make it fill the Window whenever I resize it.

However, as soon as the constraints are added, the window loses it's ability to resize.

[image]

If I add

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
```

the constraints are ignored too.

[image]

Could someone please point me where I am doing something wrong?

Code can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfif3ez5vkylh03/LayoutConstraintTest.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your `parentView` is the window's `contentView`. I can't think of a time when I've ever interfered with the default layout behaviour of this view so I'd remove the line `parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints = false`.

Secondly, by the looks of things you *do* want to take full responsibility for constraining the image view, so you for this view you *should* set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints` to false.

Finally, in addition to the constraints you add, [all `NSView` objects come with constraints that tell Auto Layout to what extent the view's *content* should effect how and whether it resizes](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2151265&seqNum=8). What's meant by content varies depending on the view, but in your case it's the `NSImage` object. In your code you're getting the default behaviour, which basically says don't allow any content compression - you need to change this:

```
imageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(249, forOrientation: NSLayoutConstraintOrientation.Horizontal)
imageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(249, forOrientation: NSLayoutConstraintOrientation.Vertical)
```

---

Really, unless you've got a compelling reason not to, you should be setting your `NSImageView` up in Interface Builder. Interface Builder not only does away with lines and lines code, it also provides live debugging help. For example, I answered this question by commenting out all of your code and redoing the whole thing up in Interface Builder first. The fact that the issue was a compression constraints thing was immediately obvious from the presence of the dashed orange warning lines that appeared whenever I selected the image view:

[image]